# Adding multiple class name to an element D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on a D3 Scatter Plot having data from different regions - here regions are Continent names like Europe, Asia etc. I want to associate the region with a class name so that I can perform common activities for one region.

Below is my code to add multiple classes together to an element:

```
var dot = svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "dots")
                .selectAll(".dot")
                .data(interpolateData(1900))
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class", "dot " + function(d) { return d.Region; });
```

When I write the following code to check what classes are associated with the current object.

```
alert(this.getAttribute('class'));
```

I got this output:

[image]

So I can see that it is adding "dot" class successfully but not able to add Region dynamically.

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have move your function, passing it as the second argument of `attr`:

```
.attr("class", function(d){
    return "dot " +  d.Region; 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Once I encountered the same problem. I expected d3.js attr() to accept collection of values to represent multiple classes and ended up searching for the solution on this issue.

Multiple classes can be passed as a result of method call:

```
.attr('class', (d) => `label item${d.itemNr}`);
```

where `label` is the first class and `item0` is the second one after this code is executed. You can add many more.

This is the result you get:

```
<text class="label item0" x="543" y="51">Item 0</text>
```

Maybe the design originates from data driven approach - you have selection of data and want to pass function of data or its result for an attribute's value. At the end, that made sense for me.