# D3.js : Adding 2nd class as an attribute for 2nd interactivity

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet, hover

First I'll describe the interactivity tool I'm currently using. Then I'll adress my request : Basically I want to duplicate this tool whith another variable.
My current project with dummy data is available at : [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/MathiasLauber/7L9k0z1h/13/)

So, I have a Legend that allows me, on hover, to highlight bubbles in the map. On the following picture I'm hovering the red legend button and it displays the red bubble on map. Everything works perfectly fine with this method.  [image: hovering red button]

For this purpose, I used an attr.`("class",...)` on line 171 of the fiddle, where I draw the bubbles.

```
 .attr("class", function(d) { return "bubbles " + d[attribute] }) // Feature for Highlight
```

I also have lines 133-150 to create Highlighting variables

```
// ---------------------------//
//       HIGHLIGHT GROUP      //
// ---------------------------//
  
// What to do when one group is hovered
var highlight = function(d) {
  // reduce opacity of all groups
  d3.selectAll(".bubbles").style("opacity", 0.30)
  // expect the one that is hovered
  d3.selectAll("." + d).style("opacity", 1)
}
  
// And when it is not hovered anymore
var noHighlight = function(d) {
  d3.selectAll(".bubbles").style("opacity", 1)
}
```

Finally, I have lines 354-372. Thats where I draw the legend and add the ability to hover-highlight.

```
   // Drawing legend 

      svg_chorop.selectAll("mydots")
        .data(allgroups)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
          return 60 + i * (size + 10)
        }) // 60 is where the first dot appears. 10 is the distance between dots
        .attr("width", size)
        .attr("height", size)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return mycolor(d)
        })
        .style("stroke", "#DCDCDC")
        .on("mouseover", highlight)
        .on("mouseleave", noHighlight)
```

My goal is to add a 2nd hover tool, that will highlight a different aspect of my data (economic sector). Thats my black boxes below.
[image: 2nd legend with black boxes]
The problem : I need to modifiy the class attributes on line 171, where I create my bubbles.

```
.attr("class", function(d) { return "bubbles " + d[attribute] }) //Important feature for Highlight   
  //.attr('class', (d) => `label item${d.itemNr}`); // possible way of adding 2nd class item, found an previous stack overflow post.
```

I found previous stackoverflow post that is a little bit similar to my request, but to general for me : [Adding multiple class name to an element D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504283/adding-multiple-class-name-to-an-element-d3)
To sum up my request :
I want to duplicate the legend and interactivty that I've just describe. This duplicate can be found on line 347 and forward (fiddle js :[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/MathiasLauber/7L9k0z1h/13/)). The problem is that I have to modify the `.atrr("class",...)` (line 171) in order to add the variable `category` that contains my 2nd filter variable (economic sector), as mentionned below in csv document.
[image]
*So if you have any idea on how to add this 2nd class, your help would be appreciated*

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Every HTML element has a `classList` property containing a list of the classes for that element. This is a read-only property, however you can still modify the list of classes by calling the `add()` or `remove()` methods on that list.

In your case, if you were trying to add a class of `category` to your `d` element, you could use: `d.classList.add(“category”)`

Comment: Hello Jack, Thank you for your answer. Im not quiet sure, where I should implement `d.classList.add("category")` . My first idea (I don't know if it is correct) was to modify line 171 on my fiddle js, where I'm creating the bubbles, as mentionned in my post (https://jsfiddle.net/MathiasLauber/7L9k0z1h/13/). It is also at this exact place you were suggesting to add `d.classList.add(“category”)` ?  thank you

Comment: I believe I may see the issue. When you are hovering over the black squares in the legend, the highlight method is triggered, and the d value that gets passed into the highlight method corresponds with the economic sector of the box you are hovering over (ex. "fin", "tech"). The problem here is that none of the circles have a class that corresponds with one of those economic sectors. Try moving the definition of the array of economic sectors (line 357) to before the method that creates the circles. Then you need to decide how you want to go about adding those sectors as classes to the circles.

Comment: Hello Jack, Thank you very much for you answer. 
Nice suggestion on moving definition of eco sector above. But I think I always have a problem wich I can't find solution:    `.attr("class", function(d) { return "bubbles " + d[attribute] }) //Important feature for Highlight` Line 176, creating the bubble, but already defined a class (prexisting percentile hovering legend), now I need to add a 2nd class for the eco hovering legend). I think if I dont add a 2nd class referring to category column in csv, it wont work. Problem : how to add a 2nd class whithout removing previous one ?

Comment: You should be able to add the second class in the same line of code on line 176. Class names can be stored as a list of classesseparated by spaces. Try adding a space and then the desired class name after `d[attribute]`  and before the `}` on line 176.

Comment: ` .attr("class", function(d) { return "bubbles " + d[attribute] d.category}) ` Unfortunately it doen't work.

Comment: It worked when you tried to implement it @Jack ? the fiddle js is here in case you need jsfiddle.net/MathiasLauber/7L9k0z1h/13